# Javascript Replace page title and Variable with Replace() Method?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, methods, replace

I noticed the JavaScript Replace() Method here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

and using this code here:

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```

I'm wondering if it can be used to replace my pages title that is set here:

```
document.title = "Supplies -" + " Orbs : " + Orbs;
```

I need to replace these items:

```
"Supplies -"
" Orbs : "
Orbs
```

The last one is a variable i defined here:

```
var Orbs = 0;
```

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Didn't you try?

Comment: Note, use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), not W3Schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that i clearly understand what you want, but maybe next will helped you:

```
document.title = ("Supplies -" + " Orbs : " + Orbs).replace("Supplies -", "someString")
    .replace(" Orbs : ", "someString")
    .replace(Orbs, "someString");
```

Answer (score -2):

Since document.title's value is a string, we can replace it with any string.

```
document.title = document.title.replace(document.title, "YOUR_STRING_HERE");
```

My bad for the last edit (using `str` instead of `document.title`)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your answer but i did not down vote it. Could you fill in the blanks for me cause i still don't see it.

Comment: So it would be: `document.title = str.replace(document.title, "document.title = "Finished -" + " Coal : " + Coal;");`?

Comment: @user3833917 nope. document.title is an object reference but the value is a string.

It would be something like this:

document.title = document.title.replace(document.title, "Finished -" + " Coal : " + Coal;");